# Is it possible to run an old MSDOS.EXE program on today's computers?

Tags: dos

I have an old MSDOS program that I might want to run on a modern(er) machine.
Is it possible to install some MSDOS on these machines and run the .exe program?
A cmd window does not work on my machine now: it's 64 bit.

This is the case, for the interested:
I am building a Win10 program to do some tricky calculation. But it's not ready yet to use. My customer comes with a question that I maybe could answer with an old program I have, that ran in DOS, back in the 80's and 90's.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.  SuperUser would be the appropriate place to ask this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an addition to emulation/VM answers: for me, big part of DOS programs worked when booted in Windows XP x32 safe mode with console support (sic!). On Vista and higher I was not able to run any DOS executable. So mostly you'll need DOSBox-like program, but XP is still a good oportunity, though.

Comment: Windows XP 32bit should be able to run dos code regardless of safe mode or not. And as far as I know x64 Windows does not provide 32 bit support when run in PXE, so it might not be able to do so in safe mode too

Comment: @Marged sounds good, but I had progrmas that refused to work in normal boot. Maybe they were too broken, but it's just my expirience.

Answer (score 3):

Any x64 based Windows will not allow you to run old 16 bit DOS code, it wouldn't be able to run 16 bit Windows code either.

I tried the same on my Windows 10 x64 only seconds ago and received this (German) denial message:

[image]

In my scenario the exe is even able to run in 386 mode with a dos extender but this does not help either because the base is 16 bit code.

You will need some kind of emulation or virtual machine. I gave [DOSBOX 0.74](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dosbox/files/dosbox/0.74/DOSBox0.74-win32-installer.exe/download) a quick try and it was able to run my old 16 bit DOS program which even makes use of an dos extender. There is no need to install dosbox, you can simply unpack the exe using 7-zip and provide it alongside your own program and use it as a launcher.

Just create a `dosbox.conf` file and put it in the same directory dosbox.exe is in. This content will automatically simulate a C-drive for DOS and launch your program as soon as you start `dosbox.exe` from Windows.

```
[autoexec]
mount C C:\yourprog.dir
C:
yourprog.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

I would try using the compatibility mode windows 7 offers (unlikely that will work).
Your best bet is an emulator like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/).